# Update Author and last saved by for files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, shell

[image]I have a list of files and its location in excel

I need your help in setting Author and last saved by Author

if thats not possible --> remove the existing information.

PS: These are different file types..

----------------------------------------------------------------
I am trying to set the author or remove the names of a file - due to privacy concerns..

I understand we can get the property with - but how to set the property

I tried looking for properties in MSDN and searched the net (because I am a novice).. but all it has is only to view or get the property not setting/removing the privacy things from the property for a file..

This is what I used to get property..

```
For Each p In ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties 
    Cells(rw, 1).Value = p.Name 
    rw = rw + 1 
Next
```

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: .                    Wow good reply

Comment: I mean what do you expect if you even didn't ask a question yet. Your post is very unclear and doesn't show any effort to find a solution, nor does it show what you have researched so far. That's why you got 3 down votes and 2 close votes. We cannot answer if there is no question or if it's unclear.

Comment: I have updated the post above.. -  just that I was unable find a solution to set the property..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the documentation of the [Workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties) is a bit miss leading as it says this property is "Read Only" while it is clearly not:

So as you can read the proprty "title" with

```
DocumentTitle = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("title").Value
```

you can write it as well

```
ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("title").Value = "my new title"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. - Hope I would be able set it from Excel vba to PPT